# ANTLR String LEXER token

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I am trying to do a STRING lexer token. My problem is that besides \n, \r, \t 
any character is himself (for example \c is c). That being said i have the following example:

```
"This is a valid \
string."
"This is
not valid."
"This is al\so a valid string"
```

After searching on the internet to no avail for me, i concluded that i must use an @after clause. Unfortunately i don't understand how to do this. If i am not mistaking i can't use a syntactic predicate because this is not a parser rule, it's a lexer rule.

Comment: Not sure what you'd want to do with `@after`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
STRING
 : '"' ( '\\' ('\\'|'\t'|'\r\n'|'\r'|'\n'|'"') | ~('\\'|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'|'"') )* '"'
 ;
```

where `'\\' ('\\'|'\t'|'\r\n'|'\r'|'\n'|'"')` is an escaped slash, tab, line break or quote. And `~('\\'|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'|'"')` matches any char *other than* a slash, tab, line break or quote.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!